# Difficulty with Caesar Cipher in C when compiling in Eclipse

Tags: c, encryption

My problem is that Eclipse is not showing me what errors I have in my code and it is compiling anyways. But when I run the program nothing happens. I do not even see the first printf line.

Okay here is the prompt:

You are to write a program that encrypts a message using a Caesar cipher. The user will enter 
the value of the key and the message to be encrypted. An example run is shown below and 
your program’s output should follow this format exactly. User input is shown underlined.

Enter shift amount (1-25):

3

Enter message to be encrypted:

Go ahead, make my day.

Encrypted message: Jr dkhdg, pdnh pb gdb.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char encrypt(char ch, int k){

    if (isalpha(ch)){

        if (isupper(ch)) {
            ch = ch + k;
            if (ch > 'Z') {
                ch = ch - k;
                ch = ((ch - 65) + k) % 26 + 65;
            }
        }
        else {
            ch = ch + k;
            if (ch > 'z'){
                ch = ch - k;
                ch = ((ch - 97) + k) % 26 + 97;
            }
        }
    }



    return ch;
}

void main(){
    int k = 0;
    char ch = 'a';
    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
    scanf("%d ", &k);
    printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
    ch = getchar();

    while(ch != '\n'){
        encrypt(&ch, k);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Encrypted message: ");
    while(ch != EOF){
             putchar(ch);

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is today official Caesar cipher day? This is the 4th or 5th question I've seen about it today! Anyway, learning to debug is an important part of computer programming good luck.

Comment: You know, you only ask for one `char`. If your encryption is correct, it does not matter how often you apply caesar-chiphre, a letter won't ever become a newline.

Answer (score 0):

With lower case letters `ch = ch + k;` may overflow a `char`.

Perform the `%26` with `int` math.

```
    if (isupper(ch)) {
        ch = (ch - 'A' + k)%26 + 'A';
    }
    else if (isupper(ch)) {
        ch = (ch - 'a' + k)%26 + 'a';
    else {
        Report_BadInput();
    }
```

Input messed up

```
printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
// scanf("%d ", &k); The space really messes things up.
// The space tells `scanf()` to keep on scanning until non-white-space is found.
scanf("%d", &k);
```

The read and print loop are messed.

```
printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
int ch;  // Use int here
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF) {
  if (isalpha(ch) {
    ch = encrypt(ch, k);
  }
  putchar(ch);
}
putchar('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your encrypt function is badly written. When you use `&ch`, you're making an integer from a pointer without casting, you should cast or create an array to store the input. In this case, there's no point on adding a return value in `main()` since it's void type and the ending point of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main(){
    static int x = 0;
    int k;
    char c;
    char cipher[ARRAYMAX] = {0};
    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
        cipher[x++]=(char)(c+k);
    }
    printf("%s", cipher);
}
```

You can wirte the encryption code in another function and use `malloc` to create an array without specifying it's size (ARRAYMAX).

Comment: This will not map `A to Z` per [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) into `A to Z`